# How to send POST data with ajax to the same razor page without refreshing

Tags: asp.net, ajax, post

i need help with this code. I have to send post data to the same page, where there is a OnPost function, but i only get the error 400
Here's the code

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var data = document.getElementById("input").value;
        $(".button").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                'url': "/Dashboard",
                'method': 'POST',
                'data': data,
                'success': function (data) {
                }
           });
      });
 });
```

Razor Page code:

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    client = new MqttLib();
    client.StartConnection();
    client.Subscribe(topic);
    client.Publish(topic, Input._status, 1, true);
    //client.CloseConnection();
    // return RedirectToPage("/Sent");
    return null;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return false">
   <input value="on" asp-for="Input._status" name="input" id="input"/>
   <input type="submit" class="button" value="test">
</form>
```

Comment: The method name is `OnPost` not `Dashboard`. If the name of your controller is Dashboard, the use `/Dashboard/OnPost`

Comment: @Bosco i tryied  /OnPost and /Dashboard/OnPost, and get in both cases error 404

Comment: What is the name of your controller? Also consider adding Route parameters to your method. Also include the data you are passing in your controller `public IActionResult OnPost(string data)`

Comment: @Bosco i mean... i have the page Dashboard.cshtml.cs that have th OnPost method...